# Grails plugin not being change after installing

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.2.1 and have created plugin in the same version and once i had already installed plugin into a project and started working but after doing some changes in the plugin 
i did `run-app` then `maven-install` and `package-plugin` again with the same plugin and removed plugin from the same project and grails but the next time when i install plugin the changes can not be seen.How can i get the changes that I have done in the plugin please help.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is fixed ..to remove the plugin we have to remove it from the projects root directory and from the grails directory in which current project is running.With these things we can get the changes after re-installing the plugin.

Comment: For future purpose, you can use refresh-dependencies for this
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/refresh-dependencies.html